# Unable To Install MySQL 5.5 for sentilo

Tags: server, apt, mysql

I am unable to install the specific version of MySql 5.5. I am using [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04). 
When I am trying this command

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5

The output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5:i386 mysql-server-5.6:i386
mariadb-server-5.5:i386 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5 mysql-server-5.6
mariadb-server-5.5 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6:i386
percona-server-server-5.6:i386 mysql-testsuite-5.7:i386
mariadb-server-10.0:i386 percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6
percona-server-server-5.6 mysql-testsuite-5.7 mariadb-server-10.0
mysql-server-5.7:i386 mysql-server-5.7 mysql-common

E: Package 'mysql-server-5.5' has no installation candidate
```

It is mandatory for me to use Mysql-5.5. I have tried other but not get any affirmative results. Please help.